# Create new sharing reason from APEX

Tags: apex, sharing, metadata-api

Is there a way to create a new `sharing reason` via APEX? Or this is *only possible via the Metadata api*?

[Sharing reasons documentation](https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/security_apex_sharing_reasons.htm)

And if not -- is it possible to specify the 'Reason' when creating a new manual share via an `sObject__share` insert?? *Even if that rule doesn't explicitly exist in the org?*

**Update**

We have discovered that we can *package sharing rules* and successfully install into a Group Test Org without an issue, so it's possible we can package our sharing rule and not touch it unless sharing is available and turned on! We'll see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sharing Reason/RowCause can only be created from the UI or through Metadata API.

It's not really a picklist on the sObject__share record, it's more like an enumerated value(enum), so you can't plug in a new value on the fly. Here is a typical construction of a Share record (if the sObject is really called "sObject". Your object is probably called something more descriptive.).

```
sObject__Share sh = new sObject__Share(
    ParentId = [objectId],
    UserOrGroupId = [userId],
    AccessLevel = 'Edit',
    RowCause = Schema.sObject__Share.RowCause.Custom_Sharing_Reason__c);
```

If the enum value has not already been created, it can't be specified as the value for the field. However, you can create a Share record with `RowCause = Schema.sObject__Share.RowCause.Manual` or with no RowCause, which will just default to Manual.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Jeremy! I think I can use this, but I can't package `__share` into managed packages (I think) due to them not being supported in *GE* & *PE*

Comment: It may be because the __share object only exists/is accessible if Organization-Wide Sharing for that object is not set to "Public". I haven't tried this, but perhaps you can have your code check to see if the __Share object exists before trying to use it.

Comment: Yeah. I'm already dynamically checking for the existence of `__share` but I wanted to provide a recognizable reason WHY rather than just `manual` which you were right, it just defaults too. If they can only be created from the API I can't use my reason unless it is manually created by the admin or packaged )8